# Add Conditional Calculated Column to R Dataframe

Tags: r

I'm needing to add a column to a dataframe that marks "X" if column 1 is greater than 0 and the preceding row's column 1 was less than 0.

So given:

`c1 = c(0,1,-1,1,2,0,1)`

`testdf <- data.frame(c1)`

I'd like to add column "new" to testdf as:

```
| c1 | new |

+----+-----+

|  0 |     |

|  1 |     |

| -1 |     |

|  1 | X   |

|  2 |     |

|  0 |     |

|  1 |     |
```

I believe it will need the usage `shift()`, which I understand enough to create a subset with the command  `subsetdf <- subset(testdf,c1>0 & shift(c1,1)<0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
i1 <- with(testdf, c(FALSE,c1[-1] >0 & c1[-length(c1)] < 0 ))
testdf$new <- ifelse(i1, 'X', '')
testdf$new 
#[1] ""  ""  ""  "X" ""  ""  ""
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
testdf %>%
       mutate(new=c("", "X")[(c1>0 & lag(c1)< 0)+1L])
```

In the `mutate` call we can also use `ifelse` as in the other post.

Answer (score 0):

If you did want use `shift` from `data.table`, you could go about it this way:

```
library(data.table)
testdf$c1_lag <- shift(testdf$c1, n=1L)
testdf$new <- ifelse(testdf$c1 > 0 & testdf$c1_lag < 0, "X", "")
testdf
#   c1 c1_lag new
# 1  0     NA    
# 2  1      0    
# 3 -1      1    
# 4  1     -1   X
# 5  2      1    
# 6  0      2    
# 7  1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do such column mutation with dplyr package and lag operator as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
testdf <- testdf %>% mutate(new = ifelse(c1 > 0 & lag(c1) < 0, 'X', ''))
```

Comment: I posted exactly at the same time. Also, I like mine better for intuitive ifelse() vs. subsetting catenated vector.